Given a bounded function $f : B \subseteq R \rightarrow R$, prove that: $sup_{x,y \in B}(f(x) - f(y)) = sup_{x \in B}(f(x)) + sup_{y \in B}(-f(y)).$
Suppose that $f : B \subseteq R \rightarrow R$ is a bounded function. 
While trying to prove: $$osc(f,B) = sup_{x \in B}(f(x)) - inf_{y \in B}(f(y)) = sup_{x,y \in B}(|f(x) - f(y)|)$$ I had some difficulties proving the following equality:  
$$sup_{x,y \in B}(f(x) - f(y)) = sup_{x \in B}(f(x)) + sup_{y \in B}(-f(y)).\tag{1} $$ 
The '$\leq$' case is rather simple:
$$\forall \, x \in B: f(x) \leq sup_{x \in B}(f(x)),
               \forall \, y \in B: -f(y) \leq sup_{y \in B}(-f(y)) \\
\Rightarrow sup_{x,y \in B}(f(x) - f(y)) \leq sup_{x \in B}(f(x)) + sup_{y \in B}(-f(y))$$
Despite the fact that we could interchange $x$ with $y$ , I have not managed to prove the '$\leq$' case.
Could anyone help me with the '$\leq$' case?

Fix $y \in B$.
Then, for each $x \in B$,
$$
f(x) = f(x)-f(y)+f(y) \leq \sup_{x,y \in B} (f(x)-f(y)) + f(y).
$$
Hence
$$
\sup_{x \in B} (f(x)) \leq \sup_{x,y \in B} (f(x)-f(y)) + f(y),
$$
that is,
$$
-f(y) \leq \sup_{x,y \in B} (f(x)-f(y)) - \sup_{x \in B} (f(x)).
$$
Since this holds for all $y \in B$, it follows that
$$
\sup_{y \in B} (-f(y)) \leq \sup_{x,y \in B} (f(x)-f(y)) - \sup_{x \in B} (f(x)),
$$
i.e.
$$
\sup_{x \in B} f(x) + \sup_{y \in B} (-f(y)) \leq \sup_{x,y \in B} (f(x)-f(y)).
$$
